# SMS/Calling redirect tracking service

Tags: sms

Me and some developers are brainstorming an idea for a project and could use some help.

In short, we want to track if a call or a text was given out with the help of our application.

it will be a consumer/owner platform. So owners will create their own business pages with information on how the consumers visiting their page can reach them by phone.

So say when the business owners are making their business page and enter their phone number, is there any third party service that will create an alias for that number, so when the consumer contacts the alias it reaches the business owners phone, at the same time sending a post-back to us (the application developers) that the contact was made through our app.

Comment: Depending on your country this is most normally done by the telephone provider by simply issuing a different telephone number for your application to give to the consumer, that number redirects to the companies normal one but is logged and the logs sent to the appropriate people monthly or quaterly.

Comment: So what software are you asking us to recommend to you?  I really feel that this question should be asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/